# selenium reclicking when server not responding

Tags: javascript, selenium

dear all:

We are using Selenium to test a web program. 
Sometimes, after our test program clicked a link, the server-side of the program is busy and not responding.
Then our test fails.
Is there a way to set an option in Selenium so that the clicking can be repeated automatically several times after some time-outs ?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: Is there a way to set an option in Selenium so that the clicking can be repeated automatically several times after some time-outs ?//

If you are using selenium Web driver , you should be able to do this in any programming language by using try catch with a counter , I could post a code sample in c# if you are interested , but not sure it is what you are looking for or the right approach for your problem

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  
Yes, it is possible to do it in python.  But repeated calling to webdriver sometimes seems quite time-consuming.  I was wondering whether webdriver can do it for us.